# I am trying to use pip to install modules, I get: AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag' Why is this happening?

Tags: python, pip, attributeerror

> C:\Users\cocop>pip --version Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\cocop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "c:\users\cocop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\cocop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe__main__.py",
>   line 2, in    File
>   "c:\users\cocop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\re.py",
>   line 143, in 
>       class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag): AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

Comment: `pip uninstall -y enum34`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27enum%27+has+no+attribute+%27IntFlag%27